# How to evaluate the following integral? [Integrand is a fraction under square root with each numerator and denominator being a 3rd degree polynomial]

Tags: definite-integrals, contour-integration

I am stuck with a integration that is related to a pendulum problem.

$$
I = \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{\pi} \int_{x_1}^{x_2} \frac{\sqrt{-x^3+(1+E)x-\bar{\beta}}}{\sqrt{x} \sqrt{2-x^2}}dx\,
$$

Note that, we have the following conditions: 
(1) $ 0<x_1<x_2\le \sqrt{2} $ ; (2) $ \bar{\beta}>0 $ , (3) $E$ can take any value

Someone told me that it would be easy to solve the integration via Contour Integration, but I cannot do it. Can someone help?

This was actually obtained by replacing, $1-\cos{q}=x^2$, in the following integral:

$$
I = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\pi} \int_{q_1}^{q_2} \sqrt{E + \cos{q} -\frac{\beta}{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{1-\cos{q}}}}dq\,
$$

First, I am not able to derive the branch points; Second, the limits are not standard and almost excludes all the poles. Therefore, I cannot proceed. Please help finding a way to do it.

If contour integration is not a way, can there be any luck with elliptic integrals? Or anything else?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Unless you include the branch points at the endpoints of the region of integration, it is highly unlikely that contour integration will be of much use in the evaluation of this integral.

Comment: Can you please guide me on how to evaluate the Branch points for this integrand?

Comment: Can there be any luck with elliptic integrals?